Where does one comment on one's own post?
I know that I can comment on my own posts (subject to qualification), but where do I do it (either on Meta or Chinese Stack Exchange)? Comment boxes, as far as I can see, are under other people's comments, so they appear further and further down the page. There is no comment box directly under any of my posts on either page. Have I misunderstood something?
I have looked on Stack exchange and on Bing, but not found anything that relates to this - as opposed to answering one's own question.

click on "Add a comment" link on your post

This link works for my post on Meta but not my post on chinesestackexchange. I should have been more precise.

You have enough rep to have the "comment everywhere" privilege, so under every question and answer (not just your own) on the main site and here on meta, you should be able to click "Add a comment" to open the comment box where you type a comment.  The process on the chinese.stackexchange.com is identical to here (and you managed to add a comment above).  Are you able to provide a screenshot?  Maybe the browser is zoomed in so far that "Add a comment" is in an area outside of the screen.  I can't think of any other reason.

Oh wait, are you thinking there's a special comment box for the poster directly under their own questions and answers?  That doesn't exist (you can edit your post instead).  When it says "comment on my own posts", it's saying you can add comments like these.  Low-rep users cannot comment on posts other than their own posts.
